# Serving file via PHP script and safe replacing this file on-the-fly

Tags: php, file, replace, download

My PHP script serves files using readfile() and manually added HTTP headers. Files are about ~1 MB big, so no partial-reading is necessary.

What is the best way to replace this file with a updated one, but ensure already started downloads won't be broken? I'd like pending downloads to be finished with fetched old file version.

Platform: Linux, PHP 5, Apache 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use version numbering in the filename:

```
$candidates=sort(glob($dir . $prefix . '*'));
$most_recent=array_pop($candidates);
```

e.g.
   file0001.pdf
   file0002.pdf
   file0003.pdf

C.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) to get a lock on the file handle - this will mean you writer process will block until it is able to get an exclusive lock.

So, your readers would obtain a LOCK_SH shared lock, and then simply use [fpassthru](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) to output the file, and finally release the lock.

The write would obtain a LOCK_EX exclusive lock, perform the write in safety, and then release the lock allowing any blocked readers to start fetching the new file.

Comment: But on a heavily loaded site you'll never get an  exclusive lock